# How to check if a hash map is empty in Typescript

Tags: typescript, dictionary, hash, hashmap

I have

```
my_map: { [name: string]: string }
```

**How do I check if the hashmap `my_map` is empty?**

I can think of `Object.keys(my_map).length === 0` but it feels overkill.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Funnily enough, your overkill solution is actually underkill; you need to go a bit further:

```
Object.keys(obj).length === 0 && obj.constructor === Object
```

Examples:

```
function isEmptyUnderkill(obj: any) {
    return Object.keys(obj).length === 0;
}

function isEmptyObject(obj: any) {
    return Object.keys(obj).length === 0 && obj.constructor === Object;
}


const a = {};
const b = { name: 'User' };

console.log(isEmptyUnderkill(a), isEmptyObject(a));
console.log(isEmptyUnderkill(b), isEmptyObject(b));
console.log(isEmptyUnderkill(new Date()), isEmptyObject(new Date()));
```

gives:

```
true true
false false
true false
```

Comment: Alright, thanks. Kind of sad! So if the object to test is **for sure** a hashmap, underkillTest is fine, right?

Comment: @mic yes - but if you're hiding it with a function, belt and braces may prevent a future bit of odd behaviour.